# java.awt.Graphics.fillRect() misbehaving

Tags: java, applet, custom-painting

Below I have a simple method for painting a set of objects onto an `java.awt.applet.Applet`. I thought this was very straightforward, but it ends up only painting the objects as a single pixel at the top-left corner of the applet. The idea is that the Display class takes in a set of fairly lightweight objects that extend `GameObject` and contain information about their location, size, and appearance on the screen, and then draws them pixel-by-pixel onto the applet, stretching and positioning them proportionally depending on the specified display height and width. In testing this, I set the width and height of the `Display` to 128, and pass two objects to the `Display`, which are both 32-pixel squares (both return `32` for `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`), one is red and returns `24` for `getX()` and `getY()`, and the other is blue and returns `16` for `getX()` and `getY()`. I put the `Display` in a `javax.swing.JFrame` and use a `java.awt.BorderLayout` to ensure it fills the frame (I use `add(display, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);` within the aforementioned `javax.swing.JFrame`).

As far as I can tell, this should be paining a blue 32-pixel square that's 16 pixels from the top and left edges and a red 32-pixel square that is either obscured by or obscuring part of the other one. However, all I get is a single red or blue pixel in the top-left corner of the `Display`. This is consistent no matter how big or small the window is.

### Code

---

```
public class Display extends java.awt.applet.Applet
{
  private int w,h;
  private ArrayPP<GameObject> gameObjects;//ArrayPP is my way of making a dynamically expanding array. It is similar to Vector, but has many more useful methods I use elsewhere.

  public Display(int width, int height)
  {
    w = width;
    h = height;
  }

  public void addGameObject(GameObject go)
  {
    gameObjects.add(go);
  }

  public void refresh(java.awt.Graphics g)
  {
    int x, y, w, h;
    final int W = getWidth(), H = getHeight();
    for (GameObject go : gameObjects)//Draw all objects
      for (x = go.getX(), y = go.getY(), w = go.getWidth() + x, h = go.getHeight() + y; y < h; y++)//Draw all lines of the object
        for (x = go.getX(); x < w; x++)//Draw all the pixels on this line of the object
        {
          g.setColor(go.getColorForPixel(x, y));
          g.fillRect((x / this.w) * W, (y / this.h) * H, w/W, h/H);
        }
  }
}
```

```
public interface GameObject
{
  public int getX();
  public int getY();
  public int getWidth();
  public int hetHeight();
  public java.awt.Color getColorForPixel(int x, int y);
}
```

### Question

---

**Why is `java.awt.Graphics.fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)` only painting the topleft corner of the applet?**

### Solution

---

The solution lies in the line that reads

```
          g.fillRect((x / this.w) * W, (y / this.h) * H, w/W, h/H);
```

wherein integer calculations cause all values to be 0. The solution is as follows:

```
          g.fillRect((int)(((float)x/(float)this.w) *W),
                     (int)(((float)y/(float)this.h) *H),
                     (int)((float)W/(float)w),
                     (int)((float)H/(float)h));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies with

```
(x / this.w) * W
```

If x and this.w are both integers and x

Convert one or more of x and w to float to force a floting point division.

```
(int)(((float)x/(float)this.w) *W)
```

Comment: +1 This has to be it, I've had to deal with this kind of thing many times before. Make sure to check for this any time you divide `int`s, like `w/W` as well.

Comment: Check the values are right before they are passed to fillRect. Check the clipRect on the Graphics. Check that the Graphics was created correctly for the correct window.

Comment: scratch that, it's how I'm calculating the scaled height and width >.<

your solution worked :3